# script tag breaks sightly data-sly tag in author mode

Tags: angularjs, templates, aem, sightly

I am using angular with sightly. So I have angular html template surrounded by script tag, which also has sightly attributes like data-sly-resource.
Below example code will give you clear idea.

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="example.html">
    <section data-sly-resource="${ @path='textOverImage', resourceType='example/components/textOverImage'}" id="textOverImage"  >
        <div ng-include="'private/textOverImage.html'" data-sly-test="${!wcmmode.edit}"></div>
    </section>
 </script>
```

It works fine in non-edit mode , but in edit mode, I can not author data-sly-resource part. It looks like `<script>` tag is not letting it work roperly because when I remove `<script>` tag ,than I can author it.

And removing script tag is not an option as well.

So how can I stop script tag form breaking sightly functionality in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing repetition of code , one for author mode and other for non edit mode.

Below is close resemblance of my solution.

```
    <section data-sly-resource="${ @path='textOverImage', resourceType='example/components/textOverImage'}" id="textOverImage"  data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" >
      <div ng-include="'private/textOverImage.html'"></div>
    </section>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="example.html" data-sly-test="${!wcmmode.edit}">
       <section data-sly-resource="${ @path='textOverImage', resourceType='example/components/textOverImage'}" id="textOverImage"  >
         <div ng-include="'private/textOverImage.html'"></div>
       </section>
     </script>
```

As you can see in above code, what to show and when works via `data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"`.

I also tried to to create sightly template for redundant code and than try `data-sly-use` but now, it works in author mode but sightly can't put template inside `<script>` tag even though I used `@ context='unsafe'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround based on the [Sightly Reference](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/getting-started.html#Working%20with%20Client-Side%20Templates)

1. Put the markup inside a separate html file say `mymarkup.html` parallel to `mycomponent.html`
2. In Component HTML file (e.g `mycomponent.html`) use `<script type="text/ng-template" data-sly-include="mymarkup.html"></script>`

In `mymarkup.html` we can use Sightly tags normally and those would be evaluated/executed normally, we would not even need to specify the `@ context` for variables we would read using use API. The final markup rendered by component `mycomponent.html` when dragged to page would render something like this below

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
    //mymarkup.html evaluated content here
</script>
```

Comment: In my opinion this is much better than the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

In your script tag you could add `data-sly-unwrap="${wcmmode.edit}"`

This will remove script tag in edit mode allowing you to edit included components but in any other mode the script tag gets rendered.

Comment: I already tried it . but it doesn't work, because data-sly-unwrap="${wcmmode.edit}" will remove surrounding tag but will leave the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following mention in Netcentric's [AEM Sightly Style Guide](https://github.com/Netcentric/aem-sightly-style-guide):

> Then, because the HTML grammar ignores elements located inside a
>   < script > or < style > elements, no block statement can be used within
>   them.

Although it's not explicitly stated in the [Sightly spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md), it makes sense. So your fix is right.